# variable.style.backgroundColor Undefined

Tags: javascript

Alright so, I have tried this a number of different ways and can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting the error that ObjectID is undefined and I don't know where to look anymore.

```
    // This is my attempt at parallax scrolling

window.onscroll = moveObj( 'box', 300, 3, 4) || moveObj();

function moveObj(elem, endpt, hrspd, vrspd) {
    elem = elem || "";  endpt = endpt || 0; hrspd = hrspd || 0; vrspd = vrspd || 1;

    //Get elements
    var ObjectID = (document.getElementById(elem) || "box2");

    ObjectID.style.backgroundColor = "Purple";

    //Set StopPoint and Speed
    ObjectID.style.left=((window.pageYOffset<endpt)?(window.pageYOffset):(-window.pageYOffset+(endpt*2))*vrspd);

    //Eliminate vertical movement
    ObjectID.style.top = (window.pageYOffset)*hrspd;
};
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: unnecesary call void `moveObj()`

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying numerous different things to see if it makes a difference. Whether 'moveObj();' is there or not doesn't affect the errors I'm getting.

Comment: Can't you attach the event handler after the moveObj function definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    moveObj( 'box', 300, 3, 4);
}

function moveObj(elem, endpt, hrspd, vrspd) {
    elem = elem || "";  endpt = endpt || 0; hrspd = hrspd || 0; vrspd = vrspd || 1;

    //Get elements
    var ObjectID = (elem);
    var Object = document.getElementById(ObjectID)
    Object.style.backgroundColor = "Purple";

    //Set StopPoint and Speed
    Object.style.left=((window.pageYOffset<endpt)?(window.pageYOffset):(-window.pageYOffset+(endpt*2))*vrspd);

    //Eliminate vertical movement
    Object.style.top = (window.pageYOffset)*hrspd;
};
```

EDIT: In that case, avril alejandro is correct in the comment to your question. There is an unnecessary call to moveObj(). I've edit to the code to remove this and the "box2" reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had 'box2' in there with a console.log originally trying to troubleshoot. I am really only trying to control 'box.' I tried the above code and it still gives me the undefined error.

Comment: I really could have sworn I tried this already. But it works, so thank you!